# sfdx:force:package:installed:list is throwing TIMEOUT error

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, sfdx-plugin, cli, force-cli

**Summary**
force:installed:list command is throwing time out error as Your query request was running for too long.

**Steps To Reproduce:**
1.ScratchOrg is created
2.Installed two packages with packageID onScratchORg
3.To display list of installed packages on the ScratchOrg, the list of installed packages with sfdx:force:installed:list -u "Orgname"

**Expected result**
List of installed packages should be displayed

**Actual result**
Showing error as 'Your query request was running for too long.'

**Additional information**
This command was working until Oct 18th, 2020. I found the errors in the pipeline since Oct 19th in all SFDX pipeline scripts and occurring frequently.

**SFDX CLI Version:** 7.62.1

is there any change happened with latest Salesforce release?

Comment: I also noticed that, were you able to find any workaround?

Comment: No, there is no polling mechanism can be added to verify this list as well. Do you know how to get run id of this command?

Comment: No, I'm considering building the query using `sfdx force:data:soql:query --usetoolingapi`...

Comment: did soql:query worked for installed packages list?

Comment: Yep, but only if I break down into two queries, if you are interested I can publish a gist.

Comment: Yes , please that would be really helpful

Comment: I suggest you to open a ticket with Salesforce, but see the workaround I was able to come up with: https://gist.github.com/jefersonchaves/041bec743a583fb691175a6e8e7943ef

Comment: Thanks Jeferson, a Bug is already reported on this https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V0000003wa2QAA

Comment: Thanks a million, let me flag that it impacts me too.